# Magento 2 Customer not notification in Status Order

Tags: magento2

Because when the status is changed, customer not notification occurs and the email is not sent.
Is there any configuration in magento 2 to notify the registered emails.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring emails in Magento 2 can be somewhat tricky. Try to install [the free SMTP extension by Mageplaza](https://marketplace.magento.com/mageplaza-module-smtp.html#:%7E:text=Mageplaza%20SMTP%20extension%20for%20Magento,comes%20to%20sending%20transactional%20emails.) and follow the setup guide. Furthermore, make sure that the settings in your backend are correct.